# convert UCS-2LE BOM encoding to UTF without losing information PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have a .csv file encoded in UCS-2LE BOM. I need to make some changes to it and I want to use preg_replace, so I want to convert the file to UTF-8. However, when I convert it, all spaces disappear and all words which belong to one and the same line are sticked together.

My code is :

```
$content = file_get_contents( "myFile.csv" );
$content = mb_convert_encoding( $content, 'UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8');
```

What is the proper way to make the conversion so that I do not lose any spaces or characters?

Before converting - screenshot in Excel:

[image]

After converting the file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should change second line into this:

```
$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2LE');
```

2nd argument is TO ENCODING, 3rd is FROM ENCODING.